# How to read library documentation downloaded as a package (package-doc)

Tags: openssl, man, libraries, documentation

I am coding Qt GUI application for cryptography and want to use OpenSSL library calls for my application logic. Thats why i downloaded libssl-dev and libssl-doc packages via Synaptic package manager (using Linux Mint 19.1).

Even though I installed -doc files I can't find them anywhere on my system: 
*/usr/lib* , */usr/local/doc* , */usr/share*, */usr/local/share* . Also typing man libssl-doc , libssl1.1 doesn't seem to work.

How can I access and read documentation package I downloaded from Synaptic ( mainly I'm interested in libcrypto documentation ) and is there a way to access libcrypto library documentation with man ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
man crypto
```

Comment: Well i'll accept it since it answers second part of the question , but I was more interested in location where libssl-doc is stored.. Anyway since I couldn't find docs, I downloaded and builded whole project from source with **make all** command that also creates documentation files that could easily be found in projectdir/doc/man3 (for man) and probably more visually pleasing **projectdir/doc/html/man3** ( still courious about default synaptic docs path tho :) )

Comment: @Tomislav I should suggested this before: `dpkg -L libssl-doc` lists all the files that the package installed. Hope it helps if you are still there.